# ExpressJS API keep insert data into DB eventhough Req didn't pass validation

Tags: node.js, express

My API built using ExpressJS has successfully create data in db, but my API keep creating data into db eventhough the req didn't pass the validation.
Here is my controller:

```
module.exports = {
    validate: function (method){
        switch (method) {
            case 'personalInfo': {
                return [
                    body('email').not().isEmpty().isEmail().normalizeEmail().withMessage('Your email is not valid')
                ]
            }
        }
    },

    createNewPersonalData: function (req, res) {
        const errors = validationResult(req).formatWith(utils.validationFound);
        if(!errors.isEmpty()){

            res.status(300).json(errors.array());
        }

        var name = req.body.name,
            email = req.body.email;

        PersonalInfo.create({
            name : name,
            email : email
        })
            .then(Personal_Info => {
                res.json({
                    'status': 'OK',
                    'messages': 'Personal Info Created',
                    'data': Personal_Info
                })
            });
    }
}
```

if I send request like:

```
{
   "name": "John",
   "email": "john"
}
```

The API should send response as

```
{
    "message": "Your email is not valid",
    "param": "email",     
}
```

My issue is the API keep creating data into db eventhough the req and res like above example.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` to stop further execution.

```
if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(300).json(errors.array());
}
```

Comment: thankyou, it's work. But it is fine to use return in sending response?

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the create call in an else block

```
createNewPersonalData: function (req, res) {
        const errors = validationResult(req).formatWith(utils.validationFound);
        if(!errors.isEmpty()){

            res.status(300).json(errors.array());
        } else {

        var name = req.body.name,
            email = req.body.email;

        PersonalInfo.create({
            name : name,
            email : email
        })
            .then(Personal_Info => {
                res.json({
                    'status': 'OK',
                    'messages': 'Personal Info Created',
                    'data': Personal_Info
                })
            });
        }
    }
```